# ui-sref on tr element won't open in new tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have repeating table rows and a `ui-sref` attribute set on them. When clicked, they navigate to the correct location. However, they cannot be <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>-clicked (or opened in a new tab).

I'm assuming this is because they set a `href` that is honored when the elements is an anchor tag (`<a>`), but not on other elements.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="view-item({itemId:item.id})">
```

Any ideas for a quick fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted with a `ng-click` function.

```js
app.run(function($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.navigate = function($event, to, params) {

        // If the command key is down, open the URL in a new tab
        if ($event.metaKey) {
            var url = $state.href(to, params, {absolute: true});
            window.open(url,'_blank');

        } else {
            $state.go(to, params);
        }

    };

});
```

Usage

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="navigate($event, 'view-item',{itemId:item.id})">
```

Comment: @designerguyit works fine for chrome but it opens a new window for firefox, any solution for firefox ?

Answer (score 0):

For a *code triggered* navigation we should use `$state.go(to, params, options)`.

#### [$state.go(to, params, options)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

> Convenience method for transitioning to a new state. `$state.go` calls `$state.transitionTo` internally but automatically sets options to `{ location: true, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: true }.` This allows you to easily use an absolute or relative to path and specify only the parameters you'd like to update (while letting unspecified parameters inherit from the currently active ancestor states).

Params:

> **to**    *string*    - Absolute state name or relative state path. Some examples:

```
$state.go('contact.detail') - will go to the contact.detail state
$state.go('^') - will go to a parent state
$state.go('^.sibling') - will go to a sibling state
$state.go('.child.grandchild') - will go to grandchild state
```

...

Also, we can inject that into `$rootScope`, so the **`$state`** *(or even `$state.go()`)* could be used later anyhwere

Check the [sample app.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/app.js) code:

```
.run(
    [ '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    // It's very handy to add references to $state and $stateParams to the $rootScope
    // so that you can access them from any scope within your applications.For example,
    // <li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('contacts.list') }"> will set the <li>
    // to active whenever 'contacts.list' or one of its decendents is active.
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

}])
```

Comment: This wasn't really what I was looking for, but it was helpful insight to understand what ui-sref was doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Good luck with UI-Router, amazing lib ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround based on the DesignerGuy solution. A directive that also supports CTRL + click and center button click.

```
    function navigate($state) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var to = attrs.navigate.split("(")[0];
        var str = attrs.navigate.split("(")[1].slice(0, -1);
        var params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eval('(' + str + ')')));
        if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey || event.which == 2) {
          var url = $state.href(to, params, {
            absolute: true
          });
          window.open(url, '_blank');

        } else if (event.which == 1) {
          $state.go(to, params);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

angular
  .module('xxx')
.directive('navigate', navigate)
```

and in the view just this

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" navigate="view-item({itemId: {{item.id}} })">
```